# Issue with parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I'd like to be able to have a SSRS report, where I can Query and find the Product Groups which accounts 80 % of the total sales over three Days *for a specific store*.

For this I've created a parameter StoreKey in SSRS. This Key generates values from a Query, and it contains all the StoreKeys present in the cube I want to import values from (there are only four StoreKeys while testing).

Having a parameter for StoreKey, I've created this Calculated Member in SSRS:

```
With Member [Measures].[Top_80] AS
select {[Measures].[Quantity]} on COLUMNS,
TopPercent([Dim Product2].[Product Group].Members, 80,
 ([Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[@StoreKey],[Measures].[Quantity])) on ROWS
from
(
     select 
     {
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-24],
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-25],
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2011-11-22]
     }
ON columns
from [Cube])
```

But this yields a cell set which displays ProductGroup, Quantity and Top_80, where Top_80's value is the string I used as an input, i.e. the whole query above as a whole, even including `@StoreKey` without having had replaced its variable name with the value I chosed while Previewing.

```
select {[Measures].[Quantity]} on COLUMNS,
TopPercent([Dim Product2].[Product Group].Members, 80,
 ([Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[103],[Measures].[Quantity])) on ROWS
from
(
     select 
     {
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-24],
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-25],
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2011-11-22]
     }
ON columns
from [Cube])
```

Works as intended in Management Studios, where I have the actual value of StoreKey "Hard coded", and where I omit the `With Member ..... AS` clause.

I have mapped the Parameter StoreKey in the dateset where I have the expression to its variable. When I created my Dataset I made it into a text from a SSAS cube, where I've chosen to include all `ProductGroups, StoreKeys, Date, Quantity`.

Does anybody have any idea as to why the query as a whole becomes the output instead of its value? From the queries I've googled I cannot figure out where I've done my syntax wrong (albeit this is my first calculated field in SSRS so I ought to Believe there are some syntax mistake or the like).

Comment: this syntax is wrong `With Member [Measures].[Top_80] AS
select ` ... `select` is not allowed to come after `AS`

Comment: this is wrong `[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[@StoreKey]` you need to use the function `strToMember`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146022.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should create a two column table - I'm a little unsure what you're using the `WITH` clause for?

```
SELECT 
    [Measures].[Quantity] ON COLUMNS,
    TopPercent(
      [Dim Product2].[Product Group].Members, 80,
      (
         [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[@StoreKey]
         StrToMember('[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[' + @StoreKey + ']', CONSTRAINED)
        ,[Measures].[Quantity]
      )
    ) ON ROWS
FROM
(
     SELECT 
     {
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-24],
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-25],
      [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2011-11-22]
     }
     ON COLUMNS
     FROM [Cube]
);
```

Comment: @whyteq        I tried to insert this query at my calculated column as an expression, but it returned the string once again instead of actually calculating the result. What I want to achieve is to create a table containing all ProductGroups, StoreKeys, Date, Quantity for each Store's 80 % most sold items per week, and in the report itself simply change the StoreKey in order to see the corresponding values of another store. Are there any more viable approach than the one I am attempting?

Comment: @Cenderze you tried inserting as an SSRS Expression - no it defintiely won't work! - the above is a query used to create a DataSet - the dataset needs to use a DataSource that is the cube

Comment: Ah of course, I tried to earlier at the "Add a new data set" but then I did not have the option to create a Query when I had selected the Data Source. However, now I noticed that one can create the Query *Before* connecting to a data source. This gave me a strange error however when I tried to parse it. It says "Failed to parse the Query to detect if it is MDX or DMX. The syntax for StrToMemeber is incorrect". I am using a cube as my data source.

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors using StrToMemeber. I've also included the StoreKey parameter in the "Query parameters" in the Query Designer. Tested some using ' and " and Parameters!StoreKey.value etc. instead of what you proposed. Nothing has helped thus far.